# Docker process from container starts on host and vice versa

Tags: docker, ubuntu, firefox

I have a host with ubuntu 20.04, and I run firefox in container from ubuntu:20.04 image.

When firefox is already started on the host: container stops immediately, new window of firefox appears, and I can see all my host browsing history, sessions and so on.

When firefox is NOT started on the host: container is running, new window of "firefox [container hash]" appears, I can see only container browsing history and sessions there (as expected). BUT when I start firefox on the host while container is still running: new window of "firefox [same container hash]" appears, and I can see only container browsing history and sessions.

If I run firefox as a different user, like

```
sudo -H -u some-user firefox
```

and having `umask 077` - I've got perfect isolation and parallel running without docker, but that's not the full goal

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox
CMD firefox
```

Terminal history:

```
xhost +local:docker
docker build -t firefox .
docker create -ti -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --name ff firefox
docker start ff
```

I suppose this behavior of process launch from container is not really obvious and expected. Could you please explain what exactly is happening and why?

Answer (score 0):

Docker container is not an isolated machine. The commands that run inside docker container are executed on the host machine (or the docker VM if using Docker for Mac).

This can be verified in the following way:

1. Run a command inside docker container `docker exec -it <container-name> sleep 100`
2. On the host machine, grep for this command `ps -ef | grep sleep`. For mac, `docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh` will provide a shell into the running docker VM.
3. On my machine:

```sh
# ps -ef | grep sleep
2609 root      0:00 sleep 100
2616 root      0:00 grep sleep
```

---

When you run a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)#:~:text=In%20multitasking%20computer%20operating%20systems,control%20of%20an%20interactive%20user.), it creates a [socket file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) in temp directory. 
This file is the gateway to communication with the application.

For instance, when mysql is running in the system, it creates a socket file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` which is used for communication by mysql client.

These daemons can also bind to a port, and be accessed through the network this way. These ports are simply socket connections to your application which are visible over the network.

---

Coming back to your question,

> docker create -ti -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --name ff firefox

[/tmp/.X11-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196677/what-is-tmp-x11-unix) is managing Unix-domain sockets. Since this is mounted within the container, the socket space between the container and host is shared.

When firefox is running on the host, the socket is occupied already. Thus the container fails to start

When firefox is not running on host and container is started, the socket is free and hence the container is able to start. This uses the filesystem inside container to store history etc. Thus you do not see the history from host.

If you run firefox from host now, it will simply connect to this unix socket and launch a firefox window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! Still I don't entirely get it. When I create similar image with the same options, only with `CMD sleep 30s` instead of running firefox, container does not fail to start, and I can see it's "Up" for 30 seconds via `docker ps -a`. So it looks like sharing sockets does not prevent container from starting. Also I can run firefox as different user in parallel (it works without sharing sessions), so it looks like sharing sockets does not prevent firefox from starting also. Then what is the cause?

Comment: Docker containers are bound to a command. This is the long-running command that is defined at the end of dockerfile. If the command fails, so does the container. Again, you can check this with `docker logs <container-id>`. As you have already seen, when running sleep command on a container, it kills itself after 30 seconds. In this case, since the socket is not available, firefox command is not successful, and thus the container fails to start.

Comment: But firefox actually starts, just on the host, not in the container. And in my case `docker logs ff` shows nothing. It used to show errors regarding `libcanberra-gtk-module`, and install of that fixed the message. Status of the container shows `Exited (0)`, like no errors occurred. If it's possible that firefox instances communicate through `Xorg` and it prevents expected launch, than why is everything ok when firefox is launched by "another" user?